# A clock or watch using a digital display to show an analog clock face

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is a term or phrase to describe a timekeeping device that uses a digital display medium to show the time by displaying hands, dots, or other indicators like an analog clock would?

Examples:
[image]

http://www.digitalwatchlibrary.com/images/made/a201_400_500_f9f9f9_imageswatermark.png_140_60_80_r_b_-10_-10_all_15_s_c1.jpg

More modern example:
[image]

Comment: It is a bit of a conundrum.  The watch has an analog display but a digital mechanism.

Comment: @HotLicks, strictly speaking, the display of such a device is not really analog, because its 'hands' move step-by-step, rather than continuously (which would be analogous to the flow of time).

Comment: @jsw29 - But the display represents an analogy of the motion of the sun (sorta).

Answer (score 6):

It's tempting to call it a *simulated analog watch* but, strictly speaking, it is still an analog watch.

> **Analog watch**
>   The name refers to the design of the display, regardless of the timekeeping technology used within the watch.
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_watch)

Comment: The term **hybrid watch** might fit if there are options to toggle between digital and analog display.

Comment: NOAD also backs you up, defining _analog_ as: **analog** (*adj.*) (of a clock or watch) showing the time by means of hands rather than displayed digits. Also, I’d be tempted to call it a _digital analog watch_.

Comment: I like '*simulated analog*'.  Surely it cannot be truly analog because the positions of the hands is not continuously variable - they are constrained by the resolution of the digital grid that displays them.

Comment: @Dan Thank you. With the term _analog_, there's some semantic drift at play here. The term can carry the notion of being continuously variable. But with _analog watch_, even mechanical ones are often quantised. The familiar 1Hz ticking of a wristwatch is due to the second-hand jumping once each second on the second. So even mechanical 'analog' watches don't need to be continuously variable. The term _analog watch_ has now come to refer to the presentation of time via the orientation of radial spokes, as opposed to via an explicitly numerical display.

Comment: ... but definitions aside, I agree that "simulated analog watch" still communicates the overall intent better in the 'truth-in-advertising' sense. :)

Comment: @Lawrence - yes, I think I see: analog watches are, in truth, less continuously variable than, say, analog vs digital sound recording...

Answer (score 2):

This design method is called a

> [skeuomorph](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeuomorph).

Pronounced /'skju ə morf/, it is a usually decorative design pattern that is in imitation of a prior, possibly necessary pattern.

The method is found all over any kind of design that allows decoration: architecture, graphic design, computer interface.

For example, neoclassical pillars aren't solid rock or even load bearing yet they are designed to look like ancient columns. Lots of features on ancient Greek temples, like plinths, socles, mutules, and modillions are decorative to evoke (non-functionally) [wooden structures in prior Greek building design](https://www.brown.edu/Departments/Joukowsky_Institute/courses/greekpast/4697.html).

Some ring tones on smartphones are made to sound like the actual physical bell ringing on older phones.

Currently the 'save file' icon is patterned after a 3 1/2 in disk which no one uses anymore.

So mimicking the hands of an analog clock in a bit pattern picture on a screen is a kind of skeuomorph.

The word itself is a modern invention though, coined by an archaeologist in the late 1800's (noticing the pattern with Greek architecture). It is made of Greek roots roots 'skeu-' meaning vessel, and '-morph' meaning 'form'.

Comment: I don't believe that this is a skeuomorph, it is a geniuine choice of display type. There are occasions where a rotating pointer display is easier to read than a numerical display as it gives a clearer indication of the passage of time. A skeuomorph in this case would be the decoration of the 'hands' with a circular boss at the centre with concentric circles on it in emulation of the rings at the ends of the hands.

Answer (score 1):

They used to be called [Liquid Crystal Analog](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US727&tbm=isch&q=LCA+watch&chips=q:lca+watch,online_chips:analog+lca&usg=AI4_-kSVPlfJaG_gGWP8sCI0ZcCZr_2JSw&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiL2YjAlrzfAhVEiqwKHWFRA9sQ4lYIKSgC&biw=1093&bih=462&dpr=1.25) (LCA) displays. I haven't found a term or acronym for the equivalent LED based displays.

Answer (score 1):

Due to their uniqueness they have been called many things but most common is probably **"Digital Hands"** Watch

Made by Gucci

Citizen
https://www.chrono24.com/citizen/seven-9560-lcd-digital-hands--inkl-mwst--id9551314.htm

Kessel  and others

[image]

For the latest smartwatch with choice of digital hands mode
[looks just like an analogue](https://www.ethoswatches.com/the-watch-guide/tag-heuer-connected-india/) see TAG Heuer Connected
[Image](https://ethos-cdn1.ethoswatches.com/the-watch-guide/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/post-1.jpg)

**Watch** this video of this amazing Intel powered wearable https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uNqJcQh8Kl0

Comment: Seems like if it were "digital hands" they would be showing us the fingers.