# Digital imitation of an analog aesthetic

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, loanwords

There is a word that refers to the aesthetic of a digital representation, imitation, or emulation of an analog device or its components.

Such as an analog clock displayed on a digital screen. Apple Inc. is well known for using this technique.

If I recall correctly; I believe the root of the word has a German origin.

Does anybody know the word?

Comment: Are you thinking of [skeuomorphism](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57164)? It's Greek, not German, but the meaning seems to fit.

Comment: It doesn't look familiar, but i could be mistaken. It is basically spot on by definition, i.e. *ornamental design cues,* and so on. You can submit it as an answer if you like, and if nobody comes up with what I am thinking of, I will credit you with a correct answer. : )

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/310769/42179

Answer (score 0):

As one commenter noted, that would be **skeumorphism,** [defined by OxfordLD as:](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/skeuomorphism)

> the use of symbols or other objects on a computer screen that look or sound like a physical object in order to suggest their purpose